# Close cat command after writing file

Tags: command-line

I am currently trying to read a device that is connected to computer using USB port.

Here is my code :

```
stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 9600 cs8 && cat -v < /dev/ttyUSB0 > /path/to/folder/file.txt
```

, which works like a charm till see the output. The only thing that makes it not perfect enough is the fact that after the output written to a file, the command is still listening the port (not auto close), so I've to press Ctrl+C manually.

So, what I should do, to auto close the command (like give it an auto-pressing Ctrl+C)?

Thank you very much.

Comment: How do you know the input from `ttyUSB0` is finished?

Comment: @zwets, Every time the device send the data it started with `^B` and ended by `^C`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is to know when to stop copying from `ttyUSB0`.

If the end of data is marked with a recognisable character or byte (say, **Z**) which is guaranteed to not occur elsewhere in the incoming stream, then the following would elegantly solve your problem:

```
stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 eof Z 9600 cs8 && cat -v < /dev/ttyUSB0 > /path/to/file.txt
```

If there is no such single character, but the occurrence of some sequence (say, **END**) can be used to detect that enough data has been read, then this:

```
stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 9600 cs8 && sed '/END/q' < /dev/ttyUSB0 > /path/to/file.txt
```

would work, on the condition that the incoming data is line-oriented. That is, there must be at least one newline after "END" or `sed` will not get to see it. (This is precisely why it is good practice to always end text files with a newline.)

Then of course, there is always the rough way. Assuming that you know the job will never take more than a minute:

```
stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 9600 cs8 && cat -v < /dev/ttyUSB0 > /path/to/file.txt &
sleep 60 && kill %%
```

Comment: Thank you for the guide. I'll try first to configure it out with the ^C character.

Comment: The end of the data is a line with `^C`

I've tried the first command to be like this `stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 eof C 9600 cs8 && cat -v < /dev/ttyUSB0 > /path/to/file.txt`

But, it still wont close. Neither the second. While the last one, succeed on the first try, than the character captured became messed up.

Comment: @thom I assume the `^C` is a Ctrl-C character. You should be able to specify that on the command line by using the sequence Ctrl-V Ctrl-C. Here the Ctrl-V escapes the special meaning of the Ctrl-C for the shell.

Comment: FYI, the displayed data is started with ^B at the first line, ^M at the end of each of the line and ^C at the end of the data. I've tried to replace ^C in `stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 eof ^C 9600 cs8 && cat -v < /dev/ttyUSB0 > /path/to/file.txt` to Ctrl-V Ctrl-C and $(echo -ne '\x03') but it still doesn't take effect.

Comment: @thom In the `stty` man page I read that `^C` (the characters caret and C) will actually be interpreted as `Ctrl-C`, so that's not the issue. One more idea (unfortunately I can't try from here): switch between `raw` and `cooked` (or `sane`) mode: `stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 cooked`. In fact, please add the output of these two commands to your question: `stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0` and `stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 -a`.

Comment: Here is the command's results : http://pastebin.com/EscRKxd2

Comment: @thom Cooked mode should do it. Could you try? If it doesn't then one more trick up the sleeve would be to set a timeout. `stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 -icanon time 50` would set a 5 second timeout.

Comment: Unfortunately, using `icanon` still can't help. I just wonder why is it so 'something'. I just reviewed your answer post and retry your last solution with `& sleep && kill %1`. Since `kill %1` gimme an error in the second execution `bash: kill: %1: no such job`, I replaced it with `& sleep && kill $!`, which should be equivalent with killing process *I got it in the internet*. So far, it works like a charm :) Thank you for your assistance, @zwets. I really appreciated it.

Comment: I have seen the `$!` before but strangely it isn't documented as a bash variable. I did some reading up, and the proper way to refer to the current job (= the last job to have been backgrounded) is to use `%%` or `%`. I have modified the answer accordingly. Can you test it out? @thom thanks for the puzzle, it was a pleasure (btw it seems you are reading lab instruments, this will be useful to me as well).

Comment: Yep. Both, `%%` and single `%` works as well. And true, it's a lab device :)